# Sound causing game to lag in swift sprite kit game?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

New code

```
class SceneTwo: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

   let flap = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("flap.caf", waitForCompletion: false)

   let whack = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("whack.caf", waitForCompletion: false)

   let tap = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("tap.caf", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Then I simply have put

run(tap)
run(flap) etc
where necessary..

Hi just wondering if I am using the correct coding to play sounds in my game. For some context my game is similar to Flappy bird. One sound is played each time the screen is touched (when the bird has impulse upwards) the second sound is when the bird collects a coin in between each wall.

I have noticed that both of these sounds are causing my game to lag.

Below is my relative sound code for the game.

```
import AVFoundation   

   var flap: AVAudioPlayer?

   var tap: AVAudioPlayer?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    tap?.prepareToPlay()


    flap?.prepareToPlay()


func playFlap() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "flap", withExtension: "caf")!

    do {
        flap = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let flap = flap else { return }


        flap.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


func playTap() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tap", withExtension: "caf")!

    do {
        tap = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let tap = tap else { return }


        tap.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

After this I have simply

```
playTap()
playFlap()
```

to where they are needed.

The sound is clear it just seems to make my spawning walls jump a little bit when the sound is made.
Is there something I am doing that is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting lag because you are not preloading the sound files. You can preload them at App Launch, and then when you need just play them. For reference look into this [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042613/avaudioplayer-and-performance-issue-in-spritekit-game)

And if you still face the same issue then you can add sound in background queue, as demostrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503629/avaudioplayer-produces-lag-despite-preparetoplay-in-swift)

```
let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
    audioPlayer.play()
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Munahil I am looking into it now!! will let you know how i go :D

Comment: Yeah, do let me know.

Comment: That has reduced the lag a fair bit! My game is still lagging a little bit whenever my walls are spawned though. do you know any other common reasons for lag? Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: You preloaded the sound files as well?

Comment: I will put the code i have now in my original question, I think i have preloaded them?

Comment: Just added now at the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130786/discussion-between-nix-and-munahil).